# zendframework 2 layout's controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i'm new to zend framework 2 and have stumbled on this problem that i can't find a answer to:

i have a layout.phtml and i want before the layout loads to have a (layout) controller fetch from my db some junk and pass it the the layout to render, so no matter if it is my application module or any other module that is running, the layout will always use the same controller.

my modules are:

> --module
>
> --application
>
> --...
>
> --src
>
> ```
>  --application
>
>    --controller
>
>      LayoutController.php <-- where i would like to hold my layout controller
> ```
>
> --view
>
> ```
> -- ...
>
> --layout
>
>      layout.phtml <-- where i hold my layout
> ```
>
> --shop
>
> ```
>  -- ... <-- shop module that uses the application's layout
> ```

and my module.config.php layout is defined:

```
'view_manager' => array(
   ....
   'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fetch some data from database and pass to layout, try this in your Module.php:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    //...

    $application = $e->getApplication();
    $sm = $application->getServiceManager();
    $application->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()
    ->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch',
            function($e) use ($sm) {
                $dbResult = $sm->get('YourModule\Model\FooTable')->bar();
                $sm->get('ControllerPluginManager')->getController()->layout()->dbResult = $dbResult;
            }
            , 2
    );

    //...
}
```

And in your layout.phtml use `$this->dbResult` for your database result.